# Producing object files with GNU make when sources are of different extensions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have three source files: `file3.c`, `file2.c`, `file3.s` which are all not of the same extension. I want to compile it into object files: `file1.o`, `file2.o`, `file3.o` which are of the same pattern.

```
OBJ = file1.o file2.o file3.o
all: $(OBJ)
#Here I am in the stuck
$(OBJ) : %.o : %.c #or %.s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

How to do this using pattern rules in GNU make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *recipe* for generating `.o` files can be made common for both `.c` and `.s` files this way:

```
OBJ = file1.o file2.o file3.o
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(wildcard $$*.c) $$(wildcard $$*.s)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The *prerequisite*, which may end with `.c` or `.s`, is determined by [*secondary expanding*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) the [*stem*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match) (i.e.: `$*`) and the [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) built-in function for the filenames resulting from concatenating the stem with the corresponding "extensions" `.c` and `.s`.

The "or" is implemented by taking advantage of the fact that the `wildcard` built-in function is expanded to *nothing* (as opposed to be expanded to the provided pattern, like the Bash shell does) if the pattern is not matched (i.e.: if there is no filename that matched the pattern provided to `wildcard`).

Comment: Either add `all` to the `.PHONY` target (as did in the last edit) or just write the dummy rule `%: %.o`.

Comment: The problem was that there is an implicit pattern rule (`%: %.o`) that was being matched by `all` which caused, in turn, `all.o` to be matched.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I will try to understand your solution.